# Django dropdown select by text

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

I have a simple django dropdown form. I want to grab the text instead of the value.

```
<select name="doctors" required="" id="id_doctors">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="3">sometext</option>

</select>
```

On selection I want to use the some text in the backend.

```
if 'bookAppointment' in request.POST:
    print(request.POST['doctors'])
    print(int(request.POST['doctors'])-1)
    print(Profile.objects.filter())
```

this prints out the value 3 is there a way to just get some text out.

```
3
2
<QuerySet [<Profile: some>, <Profile: some>, <Profile: some text>]>
```

I set it up like so:

```
bookAppointment = BookAppointmentForm()
# Make sure I get active doctors and doctors who have a refresh_token
bookAppointment.fields['doctors'].queryset = Profile.objects.filter(Q(is_active=True)&Q(is_doctor=True))
context['bookAppointment'] = bookAppointment
```

Comment: You can not do that, you will have to pass that into the value

Comment: I have a filter function as well which I could access by index.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value to your text, that way the text is passed through to POST instead of the value.

Otherwise you will need to add in some controls:

```
if self.request.POST['doctors'] == 3:
   my_var = "sometext"
```